# How can I change the outer limits of a Circular mask to a different colour

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, mask

I have the following function that is successful in creating a grey circular mask over the image input, such that the new image is a grey border around a circular image. Example: [Grey circular mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GnT9.png).

All I want to do is make the mask a very specific green, but I haven't been successful.

Here is the code:

```
function [newIm] = myCircularMask(im)

%Setting variables
rad = size(im,1)/2.1; %Radius of the circle window
im = double(im); 
[rows, cols, planes]= size(im);
newIm = zeros(rows, cols, planes);

%Generating hard-edged circular mask with 1 inside and 0 outside
M = rows;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-M/2:1:(M-1)/2, -M/2:1:(M-1)/2);
mask = double(zeros(M,M));
mask(X.^2 + Y.^2 < rad^2) = 1;

% Soften edge of mask
gauss = fspecial('gaussian',[12 12],0.1);
mask = conv2(mask,gauss,'same'); 

% Multiply image by mask, i.e. x1 inside x0 outside
for k=1:planes
newIm(:,:,k) = im(:,:,k).*mask;
end

% Make mask either 0 inside or -127 outside
mask = (abs(mask-1)*127);

% now add mask to image
for k=1:planes
newIm(:,:,k) = newIm(:,:,k)+mask;
end
newIm = floor(newIm)/255;
```

The type of green I would like to use is of RGB values [59 178 74]. 
I'm a beginner with MATLAB, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Steve

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your problem description.  Do you want to change the **boundary** of your mask to a different colour?  What exactly is your code doing currently?

Comment: Yes sorry that is confusing now that I've re-read it. I want to change the boundary of the mask to a different colour. The code currently applies a grey boundary with a blurred gaussian circular frame for the image. I've added a link to an image as an example.

Answer (score 1):

After masking your image, create a color version of your mask:

```
% test with simple mask
mask = ones(10,10);
mask(5:7,5:7)=0;
% invert mask, multiply with rgb-values, make rgb-matrix:
r_green=59/255; g_green=178/255; b_green=74/255;
invmask=(1-mask); % use mask with ones/zeroes
rgbmask=cat(3,invmask*r_green,invmask*g_green,invmask*b_green);
```

Add this to your masked image.

Edit:

```
function [newIm] = myCircularMask(im)

%Setting variables
rad = size(im,1)/2.1; %Radius of the circle window
im = double(im); 
[rows, cols, planes]= size(im);
newIm = zeros(rows, cols, planes);

%Generating hard-edged circular mask with 1 inside and 0 outside
M = rows;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-M/2:1:(M-1)/2, -M/2:1:(M-1)/2);
mask = double(zeros(M,M));
mask(X.^2 + Y.^2 < rad^2) = 1;

% Soften edge of mask
gauss = fspecial('gaussian',[12 12],0.1);
mask = conv2(mask,gauss,'same'); 

% Multiply image by mask, i.e. x1 inside x0 outside
for k=1:planes
   newIm(:,:,k) = im(:,:,k).*mask;
end

% Here follows the new code:
% invert mask, multiply with rgb-values, make rgb-matrix:
r_green=59/255; g_green=178/255; b_green=74/255;
invmask=(1-mask); % use mask with ones/zeroes
rgbmask=cat(3,invmask*r_green,invmask*g_green,invmask*b_green);
newIm=newIm+rgbmask;
```

Note that I haven't been able to test my suggestion, so there might be errors.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to implement this. won't that just overwrite 'mask' with a square array? I ran your test mask and it produced a black border around a green square...I'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, my test is probably the opposite of what you want, sorry for the confusion. Black corresponds to zero, so if you add the green/black image created from the mask to the masked original image, you should get what you want. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Soo close! Got the green border now but it's surrounding a white circle instead of a circle of the image input. I can't seem to work out this last step...

Comment: I can't see whats wrong. Try displaying an image (figure) for each step of creating the masks and the images, to see which is wrong. That is, insert `figure; imshow(mask); ` several places in code, and do this for newIm, invmask and rgbmask also. This might give some information on the problem. The rgbmask should be black, where you expect the center image to appear.